# Implementing microdata in footer.php

Tags: html, microdata

I'm trying to implement some microdata in the footer of a wordpress site.
Microdata is the following:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
   <span itemprop="name">Mivatech Security</span>
   <div itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
      <span itemprop="streetAddress">Notstraat 62</span>
      <span itemprop="addressLocality">Asse</span>,
      <span itemprop="addressRegion"></span>
      <span itemprop="postalCode">1730</span>
   </div>
   Phone: <span itemprop="telephone">+32 (0) 477 871 130</span>
</div>
```

But I'm a bit confused, cause the footer.php calls out to php code for the adress, instead of HTML:

```
<footer id="footer">
<div class="upper-footer">
<div class="block">
   <?php echo ot_get_option('b4u_address'); ?>
</div>
<div class="block">
   Tel: <?php echo ot_get_option('b4u_phone'); ?><br>
   Mail: <?php echo ot_get_option('b4u_contact_email'); ?><br>
   Btw: <?php echo ot_get_option('b4u_vat_number'); ?>
</div>
```

How can I implement the microdata in this footer?

Comment: Do you have separate fields for street, locality, region, postcode in the options where you enter the address?

Comment: Address is one field, telephone number is another extra field. So 2 fields.

Comment: OK, but you can't populate your microdata with the contents of that field because they're not separated into the fields the microdata needs. Are you prepared to hard-code the address into the microdata (instead of using the template's options)?

Comment: You mean taking out the "<?php echo ot_get_option('b4u_address'); ?>" and replace it with the microdata code? Yes, I'm prepared to do that.

Comment: In that case, you can simply replace the one with the other. You just won't be able to edit the address in whatever options interface you did so previously